# Data type mismatch in criteria expression. whats wrong?

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-update

how do I put an int variable in sql?

```
int x = Convert.ToInt32(Session["id"]);
     string MySQL = @"UPDATE users SET 
     email = '"+Request.Form["email"]+"', pname = 
'"+Request.Form["pname"]+"', accountname= 
'"+Request.Form["accountname"]+"', pid = '"+Request.Form["pid"]+"', age = 
'"+Request.Form["age"]+"',passw = '"+Request.Form["passw"]+"' where 
id='x';";
```

Comment: `id` is most likely an INT and you are trying to compare it to a letter `x`

Comment: so how do I write the int x in the sql?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please don't use concatenated values in your SQL command. You are exposing your application to `SQL Injection Attacks`. Read more [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp).

Use SqlParameters instead. It is the proper way to do and safer when you are running sql commands against your database from your application.

If a value is int covert it to integer:

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", int.Parse(Request.Form["id"]));
```

Here is a example of how to use parameters.

```
string mySql = @"UPDATE users SET email = @email, pname = @pname, accountname = @accountname, pid = @pid, age = @age, passw = @passw where id = @id;";

string connectionString = "Server=localhost\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=[your database];User Id=sa;Password=[your password];";

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
   SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(mySql, connection);

   command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", Request.Form["email"]);
   command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pname", Request.Form["pname"]);
   command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@accountname", Request.Form["accountname"]);
   command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pid", Request.Form["pid"]);
   command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@age", int.Parse(Request.Form["age"]));
   command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@passw", Request.Form["passw"]);
   command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", int.Parse(Request.Form["id"]));

   connection.Open();
   command.ExecuteNonQuery();

}
```

More about SqlCommand [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery?view=netframework-4.8).